# Android intent to enter a search query for google play music app

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello i am trying to automatically fill the search bar on Google Play Music with a String that my app provides. I currently have the intent to open Google Play Music, but I have not been able to find the right params to fill the search bar on Google Play Music. 
Here is my code

```
Intent intent = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.music");
startActivity(intent);
```

Would anyone know the right intent? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that's even a possibility?  Very few activities actually accept parameters like that.

Comment: It's worth a shot, I was able to fill the search bar in the Google Play Store app. @GabeSechan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.
 [The documentation can be found here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#PlaySearch) 
I had to choose google play music as my default music player, but after that was done the songs were searched for/played automatically with the following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ARTIST, track.getArtistName());
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE, track.getName());
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, track.getName());

            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @SabariKarthik It's an object that I was using that contains a String that I want to pass in as part of the intent

Answer (score 1):

Below is the working code to play a song with given title.

```
String title = "Iridescent";

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_FOCUS,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ENTRY_CONTENT_TYPE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE,title);               
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY,title);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```