# How can my app request Google Music play song by name/artis/category

Tags: android

I am developing an app like Google Home. It has many features and one is requested Google Music to play some music.
After a search I found that I can request Google Music play/pause music but how to request Google Music play by name/artist/category.
Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987639/android-intent-to-enter-a-search-query-for-google-play-music-app.

Comment: Thanks it works by how to control music without start music app.